# Tasker: How can I randomize a wait action?

Tags: tasker

I know how to make a randomize variable, but I don't see anywhere in the wait action to enter the variable.

I've been told to look for "crossed arrows" that will let me enter a specific value or a variable, but I don't see these crossed arrow anywhere.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just had to disable beginner mode in Tasker preferences. The crossed arrows (shuffle symbol) showed up after that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in mentioning the source and the name of the one who helped you out! https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3lieth/is_there_a_way_to_have_wait_be_a_random_time/